# how to replace text with another similar to mail merge?

Tags: php, magento, textarea, array-merge

I am working in Magento, and i have developed a module to send text messages to customers. In the settings of the module, the admin can set the message that will be sent to the customer. I'm trying to add a features that will allow the replacement of texts with data from my database.

for example, i currently have the following code that fetches the saved settings for the body of the text message:

```
$body = $settings['sms_notification_message'];
```

The message that is fetched looks like this:

```
Dear {{firstname}},

your order ({{ordernumber}}) has been shipped.
tracking#: {(trackingnumber}}

Thanks for your business!
{{storename}}
```

The goal is to have the module replace the variables in "{{ }}" with the customer and store information.
Unfortunately, i'm unable to figure out how to make it replace the information before sending the message. It is currently being send as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to use **str_replace**, like so:

```
// Set up the message
$message = <<< MESSAGE
Dear {{firstname}},

your order ({{ordernumber}}) has been shipped.
tracking#: {{trackingnumber}}

Thanks for your business!
{{storename}}

MESSAGE;

// Assign the values in an associative array
$values = [
    'firstname' => 'firstnamevalue',
    'ordernumber' => 'ordernumbervalue',
    'trackingnumber' => 'trackingnumbervalue',
    'storename' => 'storenamevalue'
];

// Create arrays $target indicating the value to change
$targets = [];
foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
    $targets[] = '{{'.$k.'}}';
}

// Use str_replace to perform the substitution
echo str_replace($targets,$values,$message);
```